# CSS style for QEdit calendarPopup

Tags: css, qt

Is there a way to style the text (month and year text color at the top specifically).

As far as I understand the popup is created dynamically when you click the dropdown button

I tried using the following code:

```
QDateEdit::down-down {
    color: black;
}
```

and

```
QCalendarWidget {
    color: black;
}
```

This doesn't work. Is there even a way to style this popup with stylesheet?

Comment: Try `QDateEdit QCalendarWidget` selector.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Nope, 
QDateEdit QCalendarWidget{
    color: black;
} doesn't do what I want it to do. In fact it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok. I don't like to customize view with qss, because in most cases it works unpredictable. Using of `QPalette` is more effective.